# How to create conditional display of column value?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

How to display a button using HTML when the value of the mimetype column is an image or PDF?

This query

```
SELECT c001    AS filename,
       c002    AS mime_type,
       d001    AS date_created,
       n001    AS file_id,
       n001   AS id,
       round(dbms_lob.getlength(blob001) / 1024 / 1024, 3) as file_length,
       dbms_lob.getlength(blob001) as Download,
       CASE WHEN c002 = 'image/jpeg'  THEN 
               '<button  type="button" class="btn-preview-pdf" data-id="#ID#">'||'Preview'||'</button>'
            WHEN c002 = 'image/png'  THEN
               '<button  type="button" class="btn-preview-pdf" data-id="#ID#">'||'Preview'||'</button>'
            WHEN c002 = 'application/pdf' THEN
               '<button  type="button" class="btn-preview-pdf" data-id="#ID#">'||'Preview'||'</button>'
       ELSE 'No display'
       END condicional
  FROM apex_collections
 WHERE collection_name = 'UPLOAD'
```

But it isn't working

[image]

Comment: Set the attribute "Escape Special Characters" to false for that column. By default it will escape and render the html characters, not interpret them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks mostly correct. Here's an improved version of your SQL query with some minor adjustments which you can try:

```
SELECT
    c001 AS filename,
    c002 AS mime_type,
    d001 AS date_created,
    n001 AS file_id,
    n001 AS id,
    ROUND(dbms_lob.getlength(blob001) / 1024 / 1024, 3) AS file_length,
    dbms_lob.getlength(blob001) AS Download,
    CASE
        WHEN c002 IN ('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf') THEN
            '<button type="button" class="btn-preview-pdf" data-id="' || id || '">Preview</button>'
        ELSE
            'No display'
    END AS conditional
FROM
    apex_collections
WHERE
    collection_name = 'UPLOAD';
```

In this query:

1. We use **IN** to simplify the **WHEN** condition, which checks if **mime_type**
   is one of the specified types.
2. We use the ***id*** column to populate the ***data-id*** attribute of the
   button.

Make sure that the HTML generated by your query is properly integrated into your web application or displayed in a way that allows the buttons to be rendered and interacted with as expected.